# Remote PC name and IP using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the remote PC names and IP address connected in the network using Java. I am able to get the IP's but can't get the names of the devices. I am attaching the code for reference.

**Java Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class findIP {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        // this code assumes IPv4 is used
        byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
        String N = localhost.getHostName();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
        {
            ip[3] = (byte)i;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            InetAddress name = InetAddress.getByName(N);
        if (address.isReachable(1000))
        {
            System.out.println(address+"            " +"Device Name: "+name);
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean like, the windows PC computer name?

Comment: Try `address.getHostName()`.

Comment: I think localhost.getHostName() return host name and ip.

Comment: @zack6849 yes I mean remote PC computer name.

Comment: @VHS tried that but it says still gives me my own computer name

Comment: @YashMehta, It probably indicates that the IP address you are passing it is your own machine IP address, not that of remote computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`InetAddress name = InetAddress.getByName(N);`

with

`String hostName = address.getHostName();`.

What you get by calling `getByName` is the IP address, not the host name. Read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)).

Comment: got the code to work with name and IP BOTH. One more question was how do I get the address and the name to segregate. When I run the code with {System.out.println(address +" "+" Name: " +hostName)} I am getting the output:  "devicename/ip       Name:devicename"

Comment: I am afraid I don't under your question. The statement `System.out.println(address +" "+" Name: " +hostName);` will not print the IP address.

Comment: Output: canonc4403f.intellig.local/10.41.27.11 Device Name: canonc4403f.intellig.local

Comment: The above is the output I am getting when I run the code. As I have one device connected to the network. How Do I get the IP to seperate from the device name.

Comment: Show the `sysout` statement that printed the above output.

Comment: System.out.println(address+ " "+"Device Name: "+hostName);

Comment: That's simple. `System.out.println(address.split("/")[1]);`. This will print just the IP address.

Comment: address.split("/")[1] did not work for me. @VHS it says method split is undefined for the type InetAddress

Comment: Oops, my bad. Try this: `System.out.println(address.toString().split("/")[1]);`

Comment: @YashMehta, glad that it worked for you. Please do not forget to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, `InetAddress.getByName(N)` is attempting to resolve your server hostname, not client. So your code should reflect your intent as :

```
String name = address.getHostName();
```

Now to answer your question, `InetAddress.getHostName()` will return the result of reverse DNS lookup for the corresponding IP address. Not all clients of your application will have a DNS record, so you may not see a "device name" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
 InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
 System.out.println(host.getHostName());
```

Comment: gives me the OUTPUT:  /10.10.10.10     Device Name: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx